# How to manipulate a python dictionary by adding object from other tables

Tags: python, mysql, django, dictionary, data-manipulation

Hi I have the following to create the data structure (List of dictionaries)

```
jobs = []
values = Record.objects.filter(record_id__in=[1,2,3], is_main_record=True, status='open', set__in=['sasi', 'kuttu','vava'])
if values.exists():
   all_item = ['sasi', 'kuttu','vava']
   for mask in all_item:
       for x in values:
           data = {'item' : x.item, 'device': x.device, 'log': x.log}
           jobs.append(data)

print jobs
```

It will return a data structure like:

```
jobs = [
        {'item': 'A', 'device': 'deviceA', 'log': 'logA'},
        {'item': 'A', 'device': 'device1', 'log': 'logB'},
        {'item': 'B', 'device': 'deviceb', 'log': 'logC'},
        {'item': 'C', 'device': 'devicec', 'log': 'logD'},
    ]
```

Now I need to manipulate the above data structure/mutating the dictionary by adding a new field named `owner`.

So as per the current database design, the table mentioned above `Record` is connected to 2 other tables names `loga` and `logb` by fields named `loga_log` and `logb_log` respectively (And Record table have `log` field to connect these 2 tables). 
And each of these tables are linked to another table named `storage` by a field named `dist_id`. This table contains the owner information (field named `owner`).

In summary (One `Record` will have only one `loga` or `logb` and these `loga` or `logb` will only have one strorage(dist_id). But a `dist_id` can have many `loga` or `logb`( Storage linked one-to-many to loga and logb tables).

Is there anyway guys I can access the owner of each record and manipulate my dictionary with that owner information without changing the database architecture? Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new field to your dictionary. It will be independent of your database.

The way will be kind of:

```
for job in jobs:
// DO YOUR STUFF...
job['owner'] = newValue;
```

You are adding another field to that specific job. You can check or recover or whatever you want before adding it.